# JenkinsFile(Pipeline script) error: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

----Below is my JenkinsFile(pipeline script)-----

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'test', usernameVariable: 'US
ER', passwordVariable: 'PWD')])
       {
sh "${gradle} -Prdsuser=${USER} -Prdspass='${PWD}'"
}
```

Here, problem with "PWD" argument which will be substitute with 2'iblm98># sample password(which has single quote')
But when i do jenkins build, getting below error due to single quote present in password.
How to escape this single quote in jenkinsfile(pipeline script) and get build successful?

script.sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If your password has no blank, you can remove the single quote aound `'${PWD}'`

Answer (score 0):

You can escape all single quotes within PWD with [String.replaceAll()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_replaceall.htm):

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'test', usernameVariable: 'USER', passwordVariable: 'PWD')]) {
    sh "${gradle} -Prdsuser=${USER} -Prdspass='${PWD.replaceAll(/'/, /\\'/)}'"
}
```

In the code above `${PWD.replaceAll(/'/, /\\'/)}` escapes all `'` occurences with `\'`.

Note that `/'/` and `/\\'` are both [slashy string](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_slashy_string)s.

Comment: ViniczaiThank you for response.

I am not sure how but below worked for me. Still my PWD value has single quote but, when i use dobule quote with back slash it worked. 

-Prdspass=\"${PWD}\"

Comment: It works because `PWD` currently does not contain any double quotes. The same problem will be encountered with `PWD='foo"bar'` for example.